# How to shutdown Firebase Emulator properly on Windows 10

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

When the `firebase emulator:start` is ran in my vscode powershell terminal, some java.exe windows pop open. Everything works great.

When I go to close the firebase emulator, using the ctrl+c command, there are logs in the terminal suggesting that everything is supposedly shutting down gracefully. Here's the log after `^C`:

```
i  emulators: Received SIGINT (Ctrl-C) for the first time. Starting a clean shutdown.
i  emulators: Please wait for a clean shutdown or send the SIGINT (Ctrl-C) signal again to stop right now.
i  Automatically exporting data using --export-on-exit "./data" please wait for the export to finish...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? i  Found running emulator hub for project une-petite-partie at http://localhost:4400
i  Deleting directory C:\Users\schar\Documents\Programming\Projects\Card Game\data\firestore_export
i  Exporting data to: C:\Users\schar\Documents\Programming\Projects\Card Game\data
i  emulators: Received export request. Exporting data to C:\Users\schar\Documents\Programming\Projects\Card Game\data.
+  emulators: Export complete.
+  Export complete
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  ui: Stopping Emulator UI
!  Emulator UI has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  hosting: Stopping Hosting Emulator
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
!  Database Emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
!  Firestore Emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  pubsub: Stopping Pub/Sub Emulator
!  Pub/Sub Emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
i  logging: Stopping Logging Emulator
```

There's a (Y/N) prompt in there, so If I type Y or N, then the terminal comes back to regular powershell stand by.

In reality, the java.exe windows stays open. At that point, if I run `firebase emulator:start` again, I get an error saying that the emulator's ports are being used. If I close the java.exe windows manually and run the emulator again, it all works as expected.

**I'm using Windows 10, powershell and VS code.** I'm not looking for a hack to clear the ports as I can simply close the java.exe windows. I want to know how to close all of it in one fell swoop within powershell. Is there such a thing? Is this an issue I should be reporting?

Answer (score 8):

I also had a similar issue. I had found two ways to solve this.

Method 1:

1. Find the port and process ID using the following command

   `netstat -a -o -n`
2. Use the below-mentioned command to kill that process

   `taskkill /F /PID PROCESS_ID`

where PROCESS_ID is the process id we got from step 1

3. Start the emulator again

   `firebase emulators:start`

Method 2:

kill all of the Java process using the following command.

```
taskkill /f /im java.exe
```

Comment: How could you automate this when shutting the tools in CLI?

Comment: In Windows, you can write a batch script for automating this. And place that batch script in the PATH. After that, the batch script you had written will be available as a command. And you don't need to run these commands again and again. Just run the custom command you had created using batch script.

Comment: In Linux, you can write a bash script to do the same and make that bash script executable using `chmod +x <filename>` command. Place this file in the PATH variable or directories such as `/bin` or `/usr/bin` and this script will be available as a command. In this way, you can automate it in the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.

1. CTRL + C in the VSCode terminal.
2. Manually close the Java Window
3. Press the trashcan icon back in the VSCode terminal windows for the task.

From that state, I am able to start the Firebase Emulator task again just fine.

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Maybe there is a better way but after being baffled myself for ages I'm glad I found something that works at least.
After you have done it a few times it gets quick enough to do it whenever you need to.

Hope that helps somebody. :)

Comment: I like this answer much more as it does not require using the cmd or netstat .... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

That java.exe window is for Google Pub/Sub emulator which is using port 8085. Manually close this window to kill the process and close the port.

Another option is to specify a different port for Pub/Sub in firebase.json config file.

```
 {
    // ...
    "emulators": {
      "pubsub": {
        "host": "HOST",
        "port": "PORT"
      }
    }
  }
```